# Number of connections possible in a BLE device

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-mesh

How many no of BLE devices can be paired with other BLE devices simultaneously?

I understand Bluetooth headsets working on BLE4.2> simultaneously allow 2 connections at the same time?
How is it with the BLE?

Answer (score 0):

There are no restrictions in the standard. So it will be implementation specific.